# DJI Simulator not working with a Phantom 3 Pro on a Windows 10

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to use DJI simulator for a Phantom 3 Pro on a Windows 10 computer but I can't get it working. I installed the program and the driver. When I open DJI Simulator, connect my Phantom 3 Pro with a USB and hit the start simulation button the start simulation button toggles on and the stop simulation button toggles off but only for a second and then it reverts back. My Phantom 3 Pro has the latest firmware.
Why is this happening? 
Thanks,
Gabe

I've tried uninstalling and re-intsalling multiple times.

Comment: Is the "SN" field empty? If it is then drone is not properly connected to computer. Does Device Manager list any issues in "Universal Serial Bus controllers? Was the driver you installed "WIN Driver Installer" from 2015-06-15? Did you try to re-connect USB-cable multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The "SN" field is empty and I did download the "WIN Driver Installer" from 2015-06-15. I've tried to re-connect USB-cable multiple times but it doesn't work. In the "Universal Serial Bus controllers" I have three devices - Intel(R)USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller, USB Mass Storage Device, and USB Root Hub (USB 3.0). Are any of these the right one? When my SD card is in the phantom it recognizes the drone and I can upload the photos but when the SD card isn't in the drone it seems like it's not recognized.

Comment: Another weird detail is that when the application opens up it is a small window and can't be resized to make it bigger.